# Determine if two different PropertyInfo come from the same interface?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.5

I've been using

```
public static bool IsSameAsProperty(PropertyInfo first, PropertyInfo second) =>
     first.DeclaringType == second.DeclaringType && first.Name == second.Name;
```

To determine whether a reflected property info matches some property I grabbed off a base class.

This approach has begun falling apart when I try to reference properties defined in interfaces.

For example, imagine the following multiple-interface inheritance scenario:

```
interface IAnimal : { bool IsHungry { get; } }
interface IDog : IAnimal { }

abstract class Animal : IAnimal { public bool IsHungry { get; set; } }
class Dog : Animal, IDog { }
```

If I'm creating property expressions, all of the following are valid:

```
Expression<Func<object, bool>> propertyExpression;
propertyExpression = (IAnimal animal) => animal.IsHungry
propertyExpression = (Animal animal) => animal.IsHungry
propertyExpression = (IDog dog) => dog.IsHungry
propertyExpression = (Dog dog) => dog.IsHungry
```

Since each of these types define or inherit the property `IsHungry`, all these expressions are valid. One might even argue they are all referring to the same property (although I can appreciate the subtle differences between an interface and instance declaration).

My problem is that I want some way of programatically detecting that all of these properties "come from" the shared interface `IAnimal` and are compatible. Unfortunately, my test returns `false` because:

- `IDog.IsHungry` has `DeclaringType == typeof(IAnimal)` whereas
- `Dog.IsHungry` has `DeclaringType == typeof(Animal)`

I can't think of an easy way to compare interface and concrete type property expressions without either resorting to a simple `Name` comparison (which is prone to false-positives) - but I can't think of anything that doesn't involve enumerating all the interfaces inherited by the two types and looking for anything with that property name that's in both sets.

---

**Q: Can we create a function that returns true when comparing any of the PropertyInfo yielded from the above 4 property expressions.** (e.g. Detect that they all represent/implement the same base interface property?)

Answer (score 0):

This will probably lead to false positives in the case of the `new` keyword being used to hide inherited properties, but:

```
public static bool IsSameAsProperty(PropertyInfo first, PropertyInfo second) =>
    first == second || // If default equals implementation returns true, no doubt
    first.Name == second.Name && (
        first.DeclaringType == second.DeclaringType ||
        first.DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(second.DeclaringType) ||
        second.DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(first.DeclaringType));
```

I suppose I could be a bit more specific and check if `first.DeclaringType.IsInterface` and vice-versa, but it's still possible to implement that interface explicitly and hide its property with a new one with the same name, so the extra check wouldn't make this any 'safer'.

Not sure if I can tell whether one `PropertyInfo` instance represents the interface implementation of the other.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with compares the getter/setter `MethodInfo` to the [`InterfaceMapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.interfacemapping). It passes all tests I could think of, but I'm not 100% convinced that there aren't weird corner cases this doesn't catch.

```
public static bool IsSameAsProperty(PropertyInfo first, PropertyInfo second)
{
    if (first.DeclaringType == second.DeclaringType && first.Name == second.Name)
        return true;

    bool firstIsSecond = second.DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(first.DeclaringType);
    bool secondIsFirst = first.DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(second.DeclaringType);

    if (firstIsSecond || secondIsFirst)
    {
        PropertyInfo baseProp = firstIsSecond ? second : first;
        PropertyInfo derivedProp = firstIsSecond ? first : second;

        MethodInfo baseMethod, implMethod;
        if (baseProp.GetMethod != null && derivedProp.GetMethod != null)
        {
            baseMethod = baseProp.GetMethod;
            implMethod = derivedProp.GetMethod;
        }
        else if (baseProp.SetMethod != null && derivedProp.SetMethod != null)
        {
            baseMethod = baseProp.SetMethod;
            implMethod = derivedProp.SetMethod;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Is it somehow possible to create a situation where both get and set exist
        // and the set method to be an implementation while the get method is not?

        if (baseMethod.DeclaringType.IsInterface)
            return IsInterfaceImplementation(implMethod, baseMethod);
        else
            return IsOverride(implMethod, baseMethod);
    }
    return false;
}

private static bool IsInterfaceImplementation(MethodInfo implMethod, MethodInfo interfaceMethod)
{
    InterfaceMapping interfaceMap = implMethod.DeclaringType.GetInterfaceMap(interfaceMethod.DeclaringType);
    int index = Array.IndexOf(interfaceMap.InterfaceMethods, interfaceMethod);
    // I don't think this can ever be the case?
    if (index == -1)
        return false;
    MethodInfo targetMethod = interfaceMap.TargetMethods[index];
    return implMethod == targetMethod || IsOverride(implMethod, targetMethod);
}

private static bool IsOverride(MethodInfo implMethod, MethodInfo baseMethod)
{
    return implMethod.GetBaseDefinition() == baseMethod.GetBaseDefinition();
}
```